# SciChart: catch click on Legend checkbox to hide series yAxis

Tags: android, scichart

I am working on the [CreateMultiPaneStockChartFragment](https://github.com/ABTSoftware/SciChart.Android.Examples/blob/master/v2.x/Examples/app/src/main/java/com/scichart/examples/fragments/CreateMultiPaneStockChartFragment.java) example and I want to catch the event when user check/unchecks checkbox in the legend so I can hide/show the yAxis of the series.
Let's say user unchecks RSI series. The series hide automatically, but a big empty space is now there. In my case I want to completely hide the area and other charts should become bigger to fill the empty space.

I don't know if this is right approach;

I modified `RightAlignedOuterVerticallyStackedYAxisLayoutStrategy` so that I can set different axis heights. Now I need to catch checkbox events - how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried the approach suggested in [this question](https://www.scichart.com/questions/question/custom-legends-showing-dashed-lines) from SciChart forums? You'll need to customize content of OnClickListener for checkBox:

```
 checkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        IRenderableSeries renderableSeries = seriesInfo.renderableSeries;
        renderableSeries.setIsVisible(((CheckBox) view).isChecked());
        renderableSeries.invalidateElement();
    }
});
```

To get access to chart instance ( and then from it to axis ) from listener you can use next code:

```
  BaseRenderableSeries renderableSeries = (BaseRenderableSeries) seriesInfo.renderableSeries;
  final ISciChartSurface parentSurface = renderableSeries.getParentSurface();
```

Hope this will help you!